# Why the 3 character minimum limit on ENS domains?

Tags: ens

Is this a technical thing? Its common across many domain services in web3, but not all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This limit is built into the name registration contract. It's here: https://github.com/ensdomains/ens-contracts/blob/0b6f79ece082234c56a532b4c6fe983ea8e9e24b/contracts/ethregistrar/ETHRegistrarController.sol#L103

Comment: Understood, but why? Was there a rationale?

Comment: I haven't seen.